# Error to cast DataGridViewButtonCell to DataGridViewDisableButtonCell

Tags: c#, casting

I'm using this [disable button class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms171619(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to disable my DataGridButtonCell but I'm having the problem that it throws an exception as it says in the title. What I'm trying to do is, when I click my  DataGridButtonCell it disables it, simple as that. I know that exist another similar question in StackOverflow but that one doesn't solve my problem.

**My code to disable the button**

```
 DataGridViewDisableButtonCell disableButton = (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)checkInGrid.CurrentRow.Cells["Button"];
 disableButton.Enabled = false;
```

**DataGridViewDisableButtonCell Class**

```
    public class DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn : DataGridViewButtonColumn
    {
        public DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn()
        {
            this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewDisableButtonCell();
        }
    }

    public class DataGridViewDisableButtonCell : DataGridViewButtonCell
    {
        private bool enabledValue;
        public bool Enabled
        {
            get
            {
                return enabledValue;
            }
            set
            {
                enabledValue = value;
            }
        }

        public override object Clone()
        {
            DataGridViewDisableButtonCell cell = (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)base.Clone();
            cell.Enabled = this.Enabled;
            return cell;
        }

        public DataGridViewDisableButtonCell()
        {
            this.enabledValue = true;
        }

        protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState,
                                        object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                                        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            if (!this.enabledValue)
            {
                if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Background) == DataGridViewPaintParts.Background)
                {
                    SolidBrush cellBackground = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor);
                    graphics.FillRectangle(cellBackground, cellBounds);
                    cellBackground.Dispose();
                }

                if ((paintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Border) == DataGridViewPaintParts.Border)
                {
                    PaintBorder(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle);
                }

                Rectangle buttonArea = cellBounds;
                Rectangle buttonAdjustment = this.BorderWidths(advancedBorderStyle);
                buttonArea.X += buttonAdjustment.X;
                buttonArea.Y += buttonAdjustment.Y;
                buttonArea.Height -= buttonAdjustment.Height;
                buttonArea.Width -= buttonAdjustment.Width;

                ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(graphics, buttonArea, PushButtonState.Disabled);

                if (this.FormattedValue is String)
                {
                    TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, (string)this.FormattedValue, this.DataGridView.Font, buttonArea, SystemColors.GrayText);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the owning column is of type `DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn` ?

Comment: @dr.null Are you saying that I should alter my button column in my Designer.cs to `DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn`?

Comment: Surely you should.

Comment: @dr.null ok, my problem now it's says that `DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn` doesnt exist in the namespace

Comment: Make sure all the classes in question within the project namespace. Rebuild, close and reopen the designer, and try.

Comment: @dr.null i'm not understanding what's happening, my `DataGridDisableButtonColumn` it's in my project namespace. In more details, that class is in a separate class file.

Comment: Fixed it, I forgot to remove `System.Windows.Forms`, thank u very much :D